# Form for nested resource Ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, submit, form-for

I am trying to do a form to add offer to product. This is what I have done so far.

routes.rb

```
resources :products do
   collection do
     get :showall
   end
   resources :offers  
end
```

offersController

```
def new
@offer = Offer.new
end


def create
@product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
@offer = @product.offers.new(offer_params)
@offer.user = current_user

respond_to do |format|
  if @offer.save
    format.html { redirect_to @offer, notice: 'Offer was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @offer, status: :created, location: @offer }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @offer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
 end


private
def set_offer
  @offer = Offer.find(params[:id])
end

def offer_params
  params.require(:offer).permit(:product_id, :priceOffer, :user_id)
end
end
```

product model

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :offers
```

offer model

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :product
```

I have actually tried to make a form by

```
<%= form_for :offer do |f| %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.number_field :priceOffer, :value => @product.price, class:"form-control" %>
</div>
<%= f.submit "Add Offer", class:"btn btn-primary"%>
<% end %>
```

but this doesnt work though.I am faced with this error

```
No route matches [POST] "/products/11"
```

I have tried changing the first line with

```
<%= form_for @offer, url:product_offer_path(@product) do |f| %>
```

but doesnt work as well :(

Comment: try accept_nested_attributes......http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for

Answer (score 0):

Try out

```
<%= form_for [@product, @offer] do |f| %>
```